# MS Dynamics CRM Quick Find

Tags: dynamics-crm, quick-search

For example, I have an entity with field "description". In the settings of this entity in "Add Find Columns" I checked field "description". "description" has follow text: "some words about entity". when I type in Quick Find field text "some words" I get my entity, but when I type text "about entity" I get nothing. This looks like search engine try to find entity with field "description" which BEGINS WITH "some words", but doesn't try to find which CONTAINS typed text. 
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a * before and after the search phrase.

So search for: `*about entity*`

The * acts as a wildcard for any number of characters.

Comment: Yeah, that works! Thanks! But it's not very well to type my search parameter with * before and after that parameter. How to customize this?

Comment: I wouldn't like to type * symbol everytime.

Comment: Like James said - I don't think this is possible, not in a supported manner anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I have found an answer.

1. Go to the following path and find "stage.js" file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics   CRM\CRMWeb_static_common\scripts\"
2. Create a backup copy of this file before any modification, so that you have the original copy too
3. Open "stage.js" in a text editor such as EmEditor
4. Find the following line of code:
   sFindCriteria=Trim(findCriteria.value.replace(/[*]+/,"*"));findCriteria.value=sFindCriteria;
5. Now change it to :
   sFindCriteria=Trim(findCriteria.value.replace(/[*]+/,"*"));if (sFindCriteria != "" && sFindCriteria.substr(0, 1) != "*") sFindCriteria = "*" + sFindCriteria;findCriteria.value=sFindCriteria;
6. Save the file and try Quick Find to see the change

Comment: Unsupported approach. Bad practice and not recommended. Can be broken during of installation of UR and so on. Good and supported way to write plugin that will handle RetrieveMultiple message.

Comment: @AndriiButenko It is working fine with RU-14. I cannot find a single way and you are telling about supported way. Post the supported way if you have any

Comment: Try to implement this approach with CRM Online and you will understand what I've meant. Supported way as I wrote - plugin that will handle RetrieveMultiple message, analyze it and replace conditions with required. I don't have source code for it now but I've done such kind of customization 2 years ago.

Comment: @AndriiButenko My problem is On-premise so take care buddy

Comment: You recommend this solution to other person. I want this person know about possible issues. So take care buddy.